# A text form field needs to be required

Tags: php

I've been struggling to have a text form field required. So when some one doesn't fill his name he will receive an error like 'No title filled!'

I got this now but it doesn't work that well cause when I submit it insert into the db.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $update = "UPDATE post SET `title`='$_POST[title]', `pic`='$_POST[pic]', `youtube`='$_POST[youtube]' WHERE id = $_POST[id]";
    $db->query($update) or die($db->error);

        if($_POST['title'] == "") {
            $error = "Title is required!";
        }
        if ($_POST['pic'] == "") {
            $error = "Picture is required!";
        }
        if(isset($error)){
            echo $error;
        } else {
        echo '<p>Your post has been updated!</p>';
        } 

 }
```

Comment: Are you making sure there are no error before running your query? Doesn't sound like it.

Comment: Show the rest of you code, how are you handling the error?

Comment: does a whitespace count as empty? just `trim()` that particular post, then compare it to `empty()`

Comment: So put the database code in the `else` section...

Comment: You can always add "required" attr to the input/textarea on the client side. At least blank fields won't be passed.

Comment: @MikeGrabowski thats true, but doesn't work for all browsers already tried it its HTML5 I think but thanks

Comment: @Benny right, as I said, nice to have, but definitely do not rely on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop your code from being executed if an error is found, not just echo the error. All your other code that submits the data to the database should ONLY be executed if there is no error. Try something like this:

Edit: Upon seeing the update to your code, this is what you need to do:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(!isset($_POST['title']) || trim($_POST['title']) == "") {
        $error = "Title is required!";
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['pic']) || trim($_POST['pic']) == "") {
        $error = "Picture is required!";
    }
    if(isset($error)){
        echo $error;
    } else {
        $update = "UPDATE post SET `title`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']) . "', `pic`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pic']) ."', `youtube`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['youtube']) ."' WHERE id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
        $db->query($update) or die($db->error);
        echo '<p>Your post has been updated!</p>';
    } 
}
```

The problem is, your data was being submitted to the database no matter what happened after with the validation - by the time you checked for errors it was too late, as the SQL had already been executed.
If you do it the way shown above, it will only submit if the `$error` variable is not set, which is what you want.

Comment: -1 for SQL Injection vulnerability. At stackoverflow, we should always inform beginners of errors they make and try to correct them.

Comment: pass the form values to `mysql_real_escape_string()` function to prevent SQL injections before you update the table.

Comment: @Mike Grabowski I was just trying to answer the question at hand - there's a lot I could suggest to improve how he was validating the data. But I do agree, SQL injection is something people should be informed of, and I guess you've made your point now, though I'm not sure it makes my answer 'not useful' to the question at hand...

Comment: @SharkofMirkwood :) Now it's time to undo the downvote, huh! //oups, seems you have to edit your answer first.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't just rely on

```
if($_POST['title'] == "")
```

because it will not work if someone enters a space into the text field. For one thing, a title shouldn't be too long? So you can set a max-length for it?

Also maybe run a few more checks such as:

I wouldn't just rely on

```
if(!isset($_POST['title'] || $_POST['title'] == "" || $_POST['title'] == " ")
{
   // Error
}
else
{
    // Database query
}
```

You want the else, otherwise it will always execute the database query, whether or not they haven't filled out the form properly.

Comment: What about 6 spaces then? :) @Benny, you should definitely delete all spaces / white characters and then, check the length.

Comment: I should have probably mentioned the trim() function! Can't believe I forgot about it. I have a function test_input($str) and it then trims it, stripslashes, mysqli_real_escape() etc, then returns the value after all that to be used.